Is it normal to understand German but can't explain/translate it, as a third language (trilingual)
I am fluent/native bilingual in French & English and I've been learning German since 2016 and have been to Frankfurt, and Berlin twice, When I did the proficiency test for University, I was placed for a second year course at my beginning.
I can write, read, speak and understand German, but the weirdest thing is, when I watch a German movie or listen to radio in Berlin, they speak fast but I can understand it all.
Let's say a friend asks: "What are they saying?"
I would be unable to translate it, as I am focused on the flow of the speech and understanding it only in a way that I can and am unable to literally explain this.
Is this normal?

This is totally normal. I am from India, and I am fluent in 3 languages (2 native and English). I have been learning German since 2020. I also happen to go quite often and live for months in Germany (Niedersachsen), where more often than not, I end up speaking in English. Their German was sometimes just way too idiomatic and informal—something completely out of the textbooks and the texts one would hear for German proficiency exams. One thing I did do, to improve my understanding was to watch videos from WDR, especially Neuneinhalb. They are short 9.5-minute videos made for a German audience.

@Joshua: If your German is as good as you claim, then you could (and should) ask your questions here in German in the future. About 95% of all questions here are answered by native German speakers. See also: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/830/1487 Btw: There are about 100 million native speakers of German, but only 80 million of them live in Germany. If you write "Schönen Abend, Deutschland", you ignore the 20 million or so native German speakers who are not German citizens (like me, living in Austria).

I'm not sure this is really a question about the German language and not a question about the way people process foreign languages in general. Some expressions are difficult to translate, and attempting to do so while continuing to follow an ongoing conversation is a trick that not everyone can pull off. Perhaps being "normal" is not to be able to do it.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about the German language.

I don't think the described effect is related to the number of languages one understands, but typically devlops with higher proficiency. If you are understanding fast speech, it means you obviously don't translate it word by word into your native language, but live somewhat in the foreign language scope. This requires creating a new summary in your native language, which is something you may find difficult even in your native language, not due to lacking vocabulary but since your rarely are asked for it.
